# convert all pandas dataframe columns to series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to convert all 10 columns in a pandas dataframe to 10 individual series. I keep tripping up with assignment operator errors when looping through the columns. So equivalent to the following without having to manually assign the series names, s1=, s2=, s3= ....

```
s1=df.iloc[:,1].dropna()
s2=df.iloc[:,2].dropna()
s3= ....
```

thanks

Comment: `s = [df[col].dropna() for col in df]` and then `s[0]` and so on?

Comment: This smells like [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to finally do?

Comment: I want 10 series in memory that I can then process with other data and plot with matplotlib, similar to the example below.
```
fixed_acidity = dataframe["fixed acidity"]
free_sulfur_dioxide = dataframe['free sulfur dioxide']
alcohol = dataframe['alcohol']

columns = [fixed_acidity, free_sulfur_dioxide, alcohol]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
columns = [free_sulfur_dioxide, total_sulfur_dioxide]
ax.boxplot(columns, notch=True, patch_artist=True)
plt.xticks([1, 2], ["Free sulfur dioxide", "Total sulfur dioxide"])
plt.show()

Comment: Really hard to read that in a comment, could you [edit] your question with it?

Comment: Your 10 series are already in the memory (dataframe). Just use [Pandas' boxplot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make a list to hold all the serieses, then loop over `df.columns`, something like this.

```py
series_list = []
for col in df.columns:
    series_list.append(df[col].dropna())
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error: # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 's1'